# testing a new window with laravel dusk

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

I have this page that, when a particular button is clicked, a new window pops up (eg. an anchor tag with _target = blank). I want to verify that a string of text appears in this new window but, with Laravel Dusk, `assertSee` appears to be testing the original window and not the newly opened window.

Any ideas as to how I can test the contents of the newly opened window?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I just ran into this problem today. You can use the browser driver to get all the opened windows, and then switch to the tab that was opened last.

```
// Get the last opened tab
   $window = collect($browser->driver->getWindowHandles())->last();

// Switch to the tab
   $browser->driver->switchTo()->window($window);

// Check if the path is correct
   $browser->assertPathIs('/path/of/site/in/new/tab');
```

You might need to add a pause after switching to the new window, since dusk is pretty fast and it may start asserting before the new page is fully loaded.

(I found this answer in a github issue, https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/336)